# SAX equivalent in .Net

Tags: .net, xml, push, sax

Is there any equivalent for SAX (Java) in .Net? I am aware of XmlReader, but I am looking for a push parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with SAX, may you like [SAXDotNet](http://saxdotnet.sourceforge.net/). Differences and extension (to Java) are explained in the documentation. Download [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxdotnet/).

There is one problem with SAXDotNet: the last change is from 2006.

Comment: Yes, I knew about it and it seems that the project is abandoned.