# Programatically filter XML in a streaming fashion (XmlWrappingReader/Writer alternatives?)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, c#-4.0, sax

I'm working with some .NET services that have the potential to process significantly large XML documents, and I need to ensure that all processing is done in a streaming / pipelining fashion.  I'm already using the [`XmlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) and [`XmlWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) classes.  My question is, what is the best way to programmatically provide a filter into the reader and writer (either, depending upon the flow)?

(I am not looking for XSLT.  I already do a lot with XSLT, and many of the things I'm looking to do are outside the scope of XSLT - or at least, implementing within XSLT would not be ideal.)

In Java & SAX, this would best be handled through a [`XMLFilterImpl`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/XMLFilterImpl.html).  I do not see that .NET provides anything similar for working with a `XmlReader`.  I did find [this blog post, "On creating custom XmlReaders/XmlWriters in .NET 2.0, Part 2"](http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000585.html), which includes the following (I've fixed the first link from a broken link from the original post):

> Here is the idea - have an utility wrapper class, which wraps
>   XmlReader/XmlWriter and does nothing else. Then derive from this class
>   and override methods you are interested in. These utility wrappers are
>   called XmlWrapingReader and XmlWrapingWriter. They are part of
>   System.Xml namespace, but unfortunately they are internal ones -
>   Microsoft XML team [has considered making them public](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/96290/make-system-xml-xmlwrappingreader-public), but in the
>   Whidbey release rush decided to postpone this issue. Ok, happily these
>   classes being pure wrappers have no logic whatsoever so anybody who
>   needs them can indeed create them in a 10 minutes. But to save you
>   that 10 minutes I post these wrappers here. I will include
>   XmlWrapingReader and XmlWrapingWriter into the next [Mvp.Xml library](http://www.xmlmvp.org/)
>   release.

These 2 classes ([`XmlWrappingReader`](http://mvpxml.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/95290#258394) and [`XmlWrappingWriter`](http://mvpxml.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/95290#259606)) from the Mvp.Xml library are currently meeting my needs nicely.  (As an added-bonus, it is a free & open-source library, BSD licensed.)  However, due to the stale status of this project, I do have some concerns with including these classes in a contracted, commercial development project that will be handed-off.  The last release of Mvp.Xml was 4.5 years ago in July 2007.  Additionally, there is this comment from a "project coordinator" in response to [this project discussion](http://mvpxml.codeplex.com/discussions/220172):

> Anyway, this is not really a supported project anymore. All devs moved
>   out. But it's open source, you are on your own.

I've also found [SAX equivalent in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745561/sax-equivalent-in-net), but [SAXDotNet](http://saxdotnet.sourceforge.net/) doesn't seem to be in any better shape - with its last release being in 2006.

I'm well aware that a stale project doesn't necessarily mean that it is any less useable, and will be moving forward with the 2 wrapper classes from the Mvp.Xml library - at least for now.

Are there any better alternatives that I should be considering?  (Again, any solution must not require the entire XML to exist in-memory at any one time - whether as a DOM, a string, or otherwise.)  Are there any other libraries available (preferably something from a more active project), or maybe something within the LINQ features that would meet these requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I find that writing a pipeline of filters works much better with a push model than a pull model, although both are possible. With a pull model, a filter that needs to generate multiple output events in response to a single input event is quite tricky to program, though of course it can be done by keeping track of the state. So I think that looking for a SAX-like approach makes sense.

I would look again at SaxDotNet or equivalents. Be prepared to look at the source code and bend it to your needs; consider contributing back your improvements. Intrinsically the job it is doing is very simple: a loop that reads events from the (pull) input and writes events to the (push) output. In fact, it's so simple that perhaps the reason it hasn't changed since 2006 is that it doesn't need to.